# Form not submitting after adding rule to htaccess

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, forms, .htaccess

I've seen similar questions on here but their fixes don't seem to work.

So to make the contact form URL a bit cleaner I have this rewrite rule in place in the htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^contact/$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/contact.php [NC,L,B]
```

Entire htaccess looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.net/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^contact/$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/contact.php [NC,L,B]
```

Submitting the form on `/contact/` doesn't work, but it does if I directly access `/contact.php`.

Within `/contact.php` it's using `/js/contact_me.js` and `/mail/contact_me.php` from Bootstrap.

The form opening tag looks like this:

```
<form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" method="post" novalidate>
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: Just use: `RewriteRule ^contact/?$ /contact.php [NC,L]` as `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` points to filesystem path.

Comment: it is because of the `/` at end of the rule eg. `contact/` try to add action with trailing slash in `<form>` tag or remove it from the .htaccess

Comment: Thanks, sadly none of those suggestions work :(

Comment: What other directives do you have in `.htaccess`? Do you have a physical directory called `/contact`?

Comment: No physical directory called, /contact. Have added the rest of the htaccess to the question.

Comment: Try `Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews` (replacing your current `Options` directive).

Comment: @MrWhite, didn't work :(

Comment: Would I be better off just having the physical /contact directory and moving /contact.php in there and renaming it index.php?

Comment: Just to confirm, you have removed `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` as anubhava suggested? (You will certainly need to do that.) No, creating a `/contact` subdirectory is unnecessary (in fact, that could complicate matters).

Comment: Done but nothing :(

Comment: "The form opening tag looks like this" - Where's the `action` attribute?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153956/discussion-between-aphextwig-and-mrwhite).